# Checking for debug symbols in .o file

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, gdb

I know how to search for debug symbols in a binary file. The question is how can I check that in an object `.o` file? Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried `nm -a file`?

Comment: OK. I see some symbols there. Do you mean `.debug_macro` section?

Comment: Possibly, but from what I've checked it might be platform-dependent. Another, more verbose and presumably better option is [dwarfdump](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dwarfdump.1.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is how can I check that in an object .o file? Is that possible?

It's possible but platform-dependent.

`objdump -g foo.o` or `readelf -wi foo.o` should show a lot of info *IFF* the object was compiled with debug info.

> `.debug_macro` section?

Presense of this section indicates that in fact the object file was compiled with debug info.